# Get column from 2D array – how to restrict array type in extension?

Tags: arrays, swift

I'd like to extend Array in Swift to return a single element in each array, or column, for a 2D array. So far I have:

```
extension Array where // what goes here?
    func getColumn( column: Int ) -> [ Int ] {
        return self.map { $0[ column ] }
    }
}
```

I believe that I need to somehow specify a 2D array after `where`, but I have been unable to figure out the correct way to do that.

**What is the correct syntax for specifying a 2D array after the `where`?**

I'm also curious if there is a good documentation for how to specify what is available for after `where` in an extension lives. I couldn't find that at [Apple's Swift extension documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have changed the title a bit, so that other questions about retrieving an array column can be redirected here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to constrain the `Element` type of the array. The subscript method is defined in the `CollectionType` protocol:

```
public protocol CollectionType : Indexable, SequenceType {
    // ...
    public subscript (position: Self.Index) -> Self.Generator.Element { get }
    // ...
}
```

Therefore you can define an extension method for arrays whose elements are collections:

```
extension Array where Element : CollectionType {
    func getColumn(column : Element.Index) -> [ Element.Generator.Element ] {
        return self.map { $0[ column ] }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
let c = a.getColumn(1)

print(c) // [2, 5]
```

You could even define it as an additional subscripting method:

```
extension Array where Element : CollectionType {
    subscript(column column : Element.Index) -> [ Element.Generator.Element ] {
        return map { $0[ column ] }
    }
}

let a = [["a", "b", "c"], [ "d", "e", "f" ]]
let c = a[column: 2]
print(c) // ["c", "f"]
```

---

Update for **Swift 3:**

```
extension Array where Element : Collection {
    func getColumn(column : Element.Index) -> [ Element.Iterator.Element ] {
        return self.map { $0[ column ] }
    }
}
```

or as subscript:

```
extension Array where Element : Collection {
    subscript(column column : Element.Index) -> [ Element.Iterator.Element ] {
        return map { $0[ column ] }
    }
}
```

Comment: Swift 3: CollectionType replaced with Collection and Generator is Iterator so we have: extension Array where Element : Collection {
    func getColumn(column : Element.Index) -> [ Element.Iterator.Element ] {
        return self.map { $0[ column ] }
    }
}

Comment: 1. For Swift4 can you need to update `Generator` to `Iterator`? 2.  In layman terms can you tell me why `-> Element` doesn't work and that you need to do `-> [ Element.Iterator.Element ]`? Because if I do `-> Element` I get the following error: **Cannot convert return expression of type '[Element.Element]' to return type 'Element'**

Comment: @Honey: The Swift 3 version should work in Swift 4 as well.

Comment: It doesn't compile for me on Xcode 9.4.1 I get the following errors: **'Array.Element' does not have a member type named 'Generator'; did you mean 'Generator'?** &
**'Generator' has been renamed to 'Iterator'** And can answer my other question as well

Comment: @Honey: Did you use the "Update for Swift 3" version at the end of the answer?

Comment: No I was trying  to do the `getColumn` way first.

Comment: @Honey: `Element` is some collection, not necessarily an array.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. If I was to keep the `-> Element` part then was there anyway to change what was being returned to a Collection type so that would it be a Collection returned? What I don't understand is that isn't `$0[column]` also of Collection type? So this should have worked

Comment: FWIW if you change your extend `Sequence` rather than `Array` then it will also work for  `ArraySlice`