# iOS Swift Get Column from Two Dimensional Array Without Looping

Tags: ios, swift, multidimensional-array

I have a two-dimensional array called "array2D".

```
print(array2D[0]) //prints an entire row at one time.
```

Is there a similar syntax to print an entire **column**?

I've tried various syntaxes:

```
print(array2D[][0]) ...causes error  
print(array2D[,0]) ...causes error  
print(array2D[[0]]) ...causes error
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is no built-in method as far as I know, but here is a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35244584/swift-extension-where-syntax-for-2d-array.

Comment: @MartinR It's a complete duplicate for me of the question you posted.