# Swift 2D arrays: Equal rights for rows and columns

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, storing-data

Given the simple 2D array...

```
let grid = [[Cell]]()
```

...and populating with `Cells` to create a 10 row by 10 column matrix.  I can access row 7 of the grid in the following way...

```
let rowSeven = grid[6]
```

What is the simplest way of extracting all of column 7?  I know it can be done by looping through each row and extracting the seventh item in each row but I'm looking for an answer that can handle rows and columns in the same way.

I'm particularly open to the idea of using an alternative to a 2D array, since in future I may want to map and filter cells in the grid independently of which row or column they are in.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35244584/get-column-from-2d-array-how-to-restrict-array-type-in-extension

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like I need to get a deeper knowledge of collections in Swift.

Comment: The answer you refer to doesn't handle rows and columns in the same way (as per my question) but adds an extension to the collection which treats the columns as something fundamentally different to rows (and simply replaces looping through the rows with the equivalent mapping function).  That difference between rows and columns is purely an artefact of the way 2D arrays work in Swift.  Therefore, i think that it should be possible to create a model that reflects this.  (I just haven't yet worked out how.)

Comment: I think perhaps "row" and "column" values should be Cell properties and not grid properties and that the grid should simply be an unsorted container for Cells.  That appears to produce the (row/column agnostic) flexibility that I am looking for.

Comment: I am not yet sure what exactly you are looking for, but there are other implementations modelling 2D arrays, e.g. here https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/blob/master/Array2D/Array2D.swift.

Comment: just wondering, is my answer is yours need? else please let me know what is wrong with this.

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer @RAJAMOHAN-S.  Unfortunately my question was a bit vague (although I did specifically say that I knew how to extract columns).  The problem I was hinting at is that 2D arrays are not really 2D.  For example, the Grid array above is a 1D array of rows, each row is a 1D array of cells.  To extract a column it is necessary to visit and extract a cell from each row and construct the column, but the opposite is not true.  You do not need to visit any columns to extract a row of data.  Continued...

Comment: ...continued.  I was wondering if it was possible to create a true 2D structure that could handle rows and columns in the same way and not in the way that a 2D array does.  Another answer pointed out that it was possible to create an interface or protocol that simulated a true 2D but it is the implementation that interested me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create your own type (struct) that presents the interface you are looking for. Then you can implement the struct however you want and change it to suit your needs without having to change the code that uses the struct. I would expect an interface like:

```
struct Grid<T> {
    func at(x: Int, y: Int) -> T
    func at(x: Int) -> [T]
    func at(y: Int) -> [T]
    // add setters as necessary.
}
```

You can implement the above with a 2D array like you already have in either row major or column major, or as a 1D array, or as a sparse array (i.e., a dictionary where the keys are x,y tuples and the values are of T.

More importantly, you can test out the performance of each of these ideas and use the one that fits your situation best *without* having to change the code that uses your Grid struct.