# Does Swift have any easy way to get a column in a 2d array?

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, multidimensional-array, higher-order-functions

For getting a row I can easily do `print(array[3])`. 
However to get a column, I have to create an empty array, loop through all rows, and append to array. That's too much for something so simple!

Currently I have to go through all this effort to get just the column:

```
let array = [[1,   9,   29,  55,  90],
             [19,  22,  33,  59,  94],
             [33,  44,  55,  62,  101],
             [75,  80,  82,  90,  197],
             [91,  99,  104, 144, 222]]

func get(column : Int, of array: [[Int]]) -> [Int]? {
    guard !array.isEmpty else {
        print("array is empty")
        return nil
    }
    guard column < array.count else {
        print("such a column doesn't exist")
        return nil
    }
    guard column > -1 else {
        print("column index can't be negative")
        return nil
    }

    var column : [Int] = []
    for row in 0..<array.count {
        column.append(array[row][column])
    }

    return column
}

get(column: 3, of: array) // Optional([55, 59, 62, 90, 144])
```

Comment: See [Get column from 2D array – how to restrict array type in extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35244584/get-column-from-2d-array-how-to-restrict-array-type-in-extension) for a method using `map`